# Изображение в карусели не адаптируется по высоте

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap4, карусель, carousel

Может плохо искала, но так и не нашла ответ. В карусели (Bootstrap 4) изображение адаптируется к разрешениям по ширине, но по высоте остается фиксированным (принимает исходную ширину изображения). Нигде высота блоков или изображения не зафиксирована (по крайней мере, я не нашла), картинкам прописан класс img-fluid (аналог img-responsive из Bootstrap 3). Все отлично работает в Мозилле, а в Опере, Хроме - нет. Молю, подскажите, в чем проблема? Заранее благодарю!
Мой код здесь:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 50%;">
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div id="img1" class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="img/img1.jpg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div id="img2" class="carousel-item">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="img/img2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div id="img3" class="carousel-item">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="img/img3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась в косячной верссии бутстрапа. Перебрав несколько вариантов из сети, нашла рабочий:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Отсюда: http://bootstrap-4.ru/

Comment: А взять с официального сайта?